"Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution" gradle-8.3
Trtying to set up my Flutter project, but I'm coming across this Gradle error. I can't find any solutions online that work for me.
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0.
Required by:
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.0
No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.3' but:
  - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
  - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
  - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
  - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')

My current setup involves Flutter, VSCode, Android Studios.
My Java version:
java version "1.8.0_411"

I'm on Windows 11.
I have tried installing a JDK, setting up environment variable.
I've set up a path for Gradle "GRADLE_HOME"
I deleted Gradle, and re-installed it manually.

Can you share your build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties file?

Did you open the only "android" file with Android Studio to let the IDE to download and install the gradle?

This question is similar to: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
